# How to use PL/SQL stored procedure with variable

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I was using SQL Server before, and now I have to do some task in PL/SQL, and it seems to me that Oracle is totally unlogical, and I couldn't find anywhere proper, user friendly documentation.

How to write a stored procedure similar to this one in SQL Server:

```
create procedure test(
@x   int
)
as
begin
select * from table where id = @x
end
```

And if posiible just explain logic behind that pl/sql script. Thank you.

Comment: You can start from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/procedure.htm#LNPLS01336)

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_return_result_set.html

Comment: Understanding you are new to Oracle, the question is still too vague. SO isn't a "how-to" site. As suggested, you should start with the documentation. @JDro04 has already provided a very basic template of the Oracle stored procedure model.

Comment: Err ... what's wrong with [Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (x NUMBER) AS
var_table_row TABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
select * 
into var_table_row
from table where id = x;
END;
```

You need to declare a row variable to store what you are selecting.  This procedure doesn't make any sense at the moment.  Are you trying to return a cursor or something?

Edit:  I'd use a function like this to do what you are asking.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (x NUMBER) RETURN TABLE%ROWTYPE AS
var_table_row TABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
select * 
into var_table_row
from table where id = x;
RETURN var_table_row;
END;
```

Call the function like this.

```
Declare
var_row  TABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
var_row := test(2);  --passes two, returns a row.  Use row like var_row.id
END;
```

Comment: No. There is a simple table with id column. I want just pass id to SP, so that to return that row

Comment: I've edited my post to help with what I think your use case would be

Comment: after calling function, it returns only PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. and no result set, even though there is an entry for such id. What can be the reason?

Comment: It won't show anything if you don't do something like dbms_output.put_line(to_char(var_row.columnname); or something similar.  You could also debug and stop on that line to verify if you are using something like toad or sql developer.  If it didn't actually find anything it would have thrown a NO_DATA_FOUND exception

Comment: I'm using SQL Developer. And i thought that Oracle should be more or less similar to SQL Server, but it's completely different and complicated. I promise, I'll study it. Calling dbms_output.put_line(to_char(var_row.columnname); returns Error report -
Unknown Command. How can I call it so that it will return the resultset?

Comment: var_row.columnname needs to be an actual column from the table.  try select test(2) from dual;

Comment: or open the function in sql developer and click the run button.  Enter the number to be passed to x and it should open a window with the result

Comment: Thank you a lot, I would better study it, because that didn't work either. Just mad with the fact that it is complicated even in simple tasks compared to SQL Server. Still don't understand, how that product is market leader))

Comment: @Sher It is not complicated, but different. You can use direct a select statement. If you call it from c# or java you call execute query. In pl/sql you open cursor. It is easy, but you should start from beginning. Read first before to judge. Use it in databases with terabytes of data and million of rows and than tell us if this DB can be a leader or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your Proc with PL\SQL would look something like...

```
create procedure test(x IN NUMBER)
IS
begin
   select * from table where id = x;
end;
```

Comment: That returns errors: Error(4,4): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored,Error(4,57): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended,Error(5,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ;